# Finding GCD java

Tags: java

Good Day! I have a problem on my code. It has an error and here's is the picture: [image]

Here is my code:

```
private static int gcd(int a, int b, int c) {
        return gcd(gcd(a,b),c);
    }


    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        //DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("+##");
        int x1 , y1, x2, y2, gcd,
            inverted_x1, inverted_y1, inverted_x2, inverted_y2,
            x1Times2, x2Times2, y1Times2, y2Times2,
            x1raised, y1raised, x2raised, y2raised,
            computeX, computeY, computeS,
            x2inverted, y2inverted, invertedx2times2, invertedy2times2;

        try{
            x1 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
            y1 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
            x2 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());
            y2 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText());           

            int[] array = new int[4];
                  array[0] = x1;
                  array[1] = x2;
                  array[2] = y1;
                  array[3] = y2;

            inverted_x1 = x1 *= -1;
            inverted_y1 = y1 *= -1;
            inverted_x2 = x2 *= -1;      
            inverted_y2 = y2 *= -1;                                 

            jTextField5.setText("= (x" + formatSign(inverted_x1)  + ")² + (y" + formatSign(inverted_y1) + ")²" 
                    + " = (x" + formatSign(inverted_x2) + ")² + (y" + formatSign(inverted_y2) + ")²" );

            x1Times2 = inverted_x1*2;
            y1Times2 = inverted_y1*2;           
            x2Times2 = inverted_x2*2;
            y2Times2 = inverted_y2*2;                                   
            x1raised = inverted_x1*inverted_x1;
            y1raised = inverted_y1*inverted_y1;         
            x2raised = inverted_x2*inverted_x2;
            y2raised = inverted_y2*inverted_y2;

            jTextField9.setText("= x²" + formatSign(x1Times2) + "x" + formatSign(x1raised) + "+y²" + formatSign(y1Times2)
                    + "y" + formatSign(y1raised) + "= x²" + formatSign(x2Times2) + "x" + formatSign(x2raised) + "+y²"
                    + formatSign(y2Times2) + "y" + formatSign(y2raised));            

            x2inverted = x2raised *= -1;
            y2inverted = y2raised *= -1;
            invertedx2times2 = x2Times2 *= -1;
            invertedy2times2 = y2Times2 *= -1;

            computeX = x1Times2 + invertedx2times2;
            computeY = y1Times2 + invertedy2times2;
            computeS = x2inverted + y2inverted + x1raised + y1raised;           

            jTextField17.setText("= " + formatSign(computeX) + "x" + formatSign(computeY) + "y" + formatSign(computeS) + "= 0");      

            gcd = gcd(computeX, computeY, computeS);
            jTextField18.setText("= " + formatSign(computeX/gcd) + "x" + formatSign(computeY/gcd) + "y" + formatSign(computeS/gcd) + "= 0");   

            jTextField6.setText("= " + formatSign(10/gcd));

            XYLineChart_AWT chart = new XYLineChart_AWT("Locus of Point Graph", "", array);
            chart.pack();          
            RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen( chart );          
            chart.setVisible( true );             

        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill necessary inputs");
        }
    }
```

the error shows at my return gcd(gcd(a,b),c);

I want to get the GCD of 3 numbers and later on divide it to my variables. Is there any other way? Or is there a way to solve the error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: gcd(gcd(a,b),c) isn't right, the inner gcd call is only taking 2 arguments.

Comment: In addition, your `gcd` method doesn't make any sense. I'm assuming its still a work in progress?

Comment: where do you intend to actually implement gcd?

Comment: You just need to implement `gcd(int a, int b)`. You don't have that in your code, even though you are calling it in that return statement.

Comment: Sorry but here is my code for gcd

    private int gcd(int a,int b, int c) {
        int gcd = 1;
        for(int i=2; i<=a && i<=b && i<=c;i++) {
            if(a%i==0 && b%i==0 && c%i==0) {
                gcd = i;
            }
        }
        return gcd;
    }

it always return to 1. Is there any wrong thing in my logic?

Comment: And so, what is the issue with the updated code (version #2)? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because when I call that with `60, 45, 90`, I get the expected `15` back.

Comment: @Diestro You can edit the question and paste the code in there. As you see, code doesn't format properly in the comments.

Comment: Please note that this question was edited to be a different question, which is why some of the comments and answers don't make as much sense now.

Comment: @Diestro for a different question, ask a new question. This should be reverted to what it was. I've rolled it back.

Answer (score 2):

Because `gcd(...)` takes 3 arguments

```
 private static int gcd(int a, int b, int c) {
            return gcd(gcd(a,b),c);
        }
```

In `return`, you are passing only 2. Also, with the code you have shown, if you pass `3` params, it will be [infinite recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop#Infinite_recursion). Thanks to @eis for pointing that out. I forgot to mention it :)

Comment: ... but if you were passing three, you'd just get an endless recursion. I guess OP needs to implement gcd for two parameters.